# Derivative with respect to multiple variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Is it true that, if both limits exist, then
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h, y + h) - f(x, y)}{h} \stackrel{?}{=} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h, y) + f(x, y + h) - 2 f(x, y)}{h} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$$
?

If this isn't always true, are there some criteria such that the statement is true for all $f$ meeting the criteria?

Comment: I think there is a shortcut. Hint: your first limit is also $\frac{d}{dt}\Big|_{t=0}f(x+t,y+t)$. Can you use the chain rule to express this total derivative in terms of $\partial_x f$ and $\partial_y f$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true if the function is differentiable, since by Taylor's theorem:

$$f(\boldsymbol{x}+\boldsymbol{h}) = f(\boldsymbol{x}) + df(\boldsymbol{x})\boldsymbol{h} + g(\boldsymbol{x} + \boldsymbol{h})\Vert \boldsymbol{h}\Vert$$

where $\underset{\boldsymbol{h}\rightarrow \boldsymbol{0}}{\lim} g(\boldsymbol{x} + \boldsymbol{h}) = 0$. That means that if you pick

$$\boldsymbol{h} = h\boldsymbol{c}$$

where $\boldsymbol{c}$ is the vector $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^\top$, then

$$ f(\boldsymbol{x}+h\boldsymbol{c}) = f(\boldsymbol{x}) + h \cdot df(\boldsymbol{x})\boldsymbol{c} + g(\boldsymbol{x} + h\boldsymbol{c})\Vert h\boldsymbol{c}\Vert$$

Then you can formulate the limit:

$$ \underset{h \rightarrow 0}{\lim} \frac{f(\boldsymbol{x}+h\boldsymbol{c}) - f(\boldsymbol{x})}{h}$$

which you should find is equal to $df(\boldsymbol{x}) \boldsymbol{c}$ since $g(\boldsymbol{x} + h\boldsymbol{c})\rightarrow 0$ as $h\rightarrow 0$. If you consider $\boldsymbol{x} = \begin{pmatrix} x & y \end{pmatrix}^\top$, then you get the result for your case since $df$ is the Jacobian.